# My mysql query where I try to cast as integer is not working and giving me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, mysql

The query:

```
SELECT e.*, 
       cast(replace(substr(annual_salary, 2), ',' , '') as integer) as salary_cleaned,
       rank() over(partition by department order by annual_salary desc) as rn
FROM employees.employees_sample e
```

> The cast statement in my select clause gives me an error '"integer" is
> not valid at this location, expecting FOR, LOCK, SELECT, TABLE,
> VALUES, WITH... "

The column is of TEXT datatype.

I imported this data from an Excel CSV file if that helps.

Please help.

I tried both cast as integer and convert functions. Both are giving me the same error.

I even tried using the function on a new created column:

```
SELECT cast('999' as integer)
```

This returns the same error 1064.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the keyword **integer** which is not permitted in the MYSQL cast function.

See official MySQL Documentation [CAST(expr AS type [ARRAY])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for the allowed types.

You could use SIGNED instead.

```
SELECT cast('999' as signed)
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/sUyvCYJf)